# Assign each sample in B to each element of a matrix A

Tags: least-squares, matrix, extreme-value

I've measured the distance between 100 brain regions and 5 "core" brain regions. This led me to a 100x5 matrix (A) of empirical distances.

Now, I have a second 100x5 matrix (B), where the distances are predicted, but rows are not ordered.

I want to assign each row of B to each row of A, using the similarities between predicted and empirical distances.
It seems a problem of multiple minima, but I don't know how to solve it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could approach this. Here are some examples:

1. Compute the residual sum of squares (RSS) for row 1 of B against all rows of A. Assign this to the row with the smallest RSS. Then compute the RSS for row 2 of B against the remaining 99 rows of A and assign. Repeat until complete.
2. Compute the RSS for each row of B against all rows of A. Then assign the rows of B to the rows of A for least error. There will likely be some duplicates - assign these to the remaining unmatched rows.
3. 'Brute force' it by calculating the total matrix RSS for all possible permutations of the rows of B but given than 100! is large, this may take a while...

As you suggest, methods 1 and 2 will arrive you at local minima that may be fairly close to the global solution. Method 3 will arrive at the global solution.